# How to call an index of a multidimensional array in Java

Tags: multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array which I don't know how to "call" in a specific index.

Here is my code :

```
        List<String[]> stats = new ArrayList<>();
        stats.add(new String[11]);
        String currentDate = null;
        String nextDate = null;
        String prize = null;
        int j = 0;
        for(i = 1; i < statsFromFile.size(); i++) {
            currentDate = toStringDate(statsFromFile.get(i).get(0), date, sdf);
            nextDate = toStringDate(statsFromFile.get(i+1).get(0), date, sdf);
            prize = statsFromFile.get(i).get(1);
            stats.get(j)[0] = currentDate;
            if(currentDate.equals(nextDate)) {

                stats.get(j)[4]++; // Here's the problematic line.

            }
            else {
                stats.add(new String[11]);
                j++;
                prize = statsFromFile.get(j).get(0);

                stats.get(j)[1]++; // And here too.

            }
        }
```

Before, the array was a long-type array and it worked well, but now that is a String-type array, it seems to doesn't work the same way.

I have this error : `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int`

Comment: Another array with String data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax is wrong on both lines:

```
stats.get(j)[4]++;
```

What do you expect the ++ to do in this case?

`stats.get(j)[4]` is accessing the 4th Element on the j-array in our list, which is a string array and your calling a mathimatical operator on the 4th element which is a string.

Comment: Rhaa dammit, of course. I have to increment this index, but now that the array is no longer in long-type, I have to find another way to do it. Thanks for your time :) (I'll accept your answer in 4 minutes ;) )